# Kubernetes: Frontend-Pod cannot resolve dns of Backend-Service (using Minikube)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns, minikube

I am learning Kubernetes and i run into trouble reaching an API in my local Minikube (Docker driver).
I have a pod running an angluar-client which tries to reach a backend pod. The frontend Pod is exposed by a NodePort Service. The backend pod is exposed to the Cluster by a ClusterIP Service.

But when i try to reach the clusterip service from the frontend the dns `transpile-svc.default.svc.cluster.local` cannot get resolved.
[error message in the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEaQ6.png)

the dns should work properly. i followed this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/  and deployed a dnsutils pod from where i can `nslookup`.

```
winpty kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup transpile-svc.default
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   transpile-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.99.196.82
```

This is the .yaml file for the clusterIP Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: transpile-svc
  labels: 
    app: transpile
spec:
  selector:
    app: transpile
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Even if i hardcode the IP into the request of the frontend i am getting an empty response.
I verified, that the backend pod is working correctly and when i expose it as a NodePort i can reach the api with my browser.

What am i missing here? Im stuck with this problems for quite some time now and i dont find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your frontend application is calling your application from outside the cluster you need to expose your backend application to outside network too.

There are two ways: either expose it directly by changing transpile-svc service to loadbalancer type or introduce an ingress controller(eg Nginx ingress controller with an Ingres object) which will handle all redirections

Steps to expose service as loadbalancer in minikube

1.Change your service transpile-svc type to LoadBalancer
2.Run command minikube service transpile-svc to expose the service ie an IP will be allocated.
3. Run kubectl get services to get external IP assigned. Use IP:POST to call from frontend application

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As i mentioned in the comments of the other answer both pods (front and backend) ar in the same cluster and in the same namespace. I want to establish communication in the cluster

Comment: I get that they are in the same cluster and namespace. But your application is being accessed from outside the cluster. Either you can make your front end application just a static UI application and you can expose the backend application directly or you can make it a server which can redirect requests internally as shown by Arghya Sadhu . I will recommend backend service exposed separately as it is more scalable.

Comment: Okay maybe i did not got the concept of the clusterIP Service right. So what is the sense of a clusterip service overall?

Comment: in the end i just want to have multiple containers in a cluster talking to each other.

Comment: clusterip is used for inter-cluster communication.. when an outside world does not interact with your clutser eg let suppose you have 3 internal backend applications and then have to communicate with each other. then these can communicate with each other with service names directly. Where as if any application needs to be publically available ie you can call it from anywhere then you need to expose it via load balancer or public ip.

Comment: So generally we have one ingress controller application exposed publically. All request comes to that application and which can then proxy it to required service internally using domain or path based routing. I hope things are clear now,

Answer (score 0):

DNS hostnames `*.*.svc.cluster.local` is only resolvable from within the kubernetes cluster. You should use `http://NODEIP:NODEPORT` or url provided by `minikube service transpile-svc --url` in the frontend javascript code which is running in a browser outside the kubernetes cluster.

If the frontend pod is nginx then you can configure the backend service name as below in the nginx configuration file as described in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/)

```
upstream transpile {
    server transpile;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://transpile-svc;
    }
}
```

Comment: the frontend is a pod running in the cluster within the same namespace

Comment: If I understand correctly you are making a call to  `transpile-svc.default.svc.cluster.local` from a javascript code which runs in browser

Comment: No sorry if i was unclear in the question :)  i am making this call in the cluster both pods are running in the same namespace

Comment: Well..the screenshot of the error that you have in the question..isn't from a browser?

Comment: yes it is. i exposed the pod that is making the request using a NodePort Service. with `minikube service client-svc` i can reach this pod in my browser

Comment: What are running as frontend pod..nginx?

Comment: You need to configure nginx config file to the backend service name..I have added some reference

Comment: Thanks this may help a lot! Do you know where i can find that conf file?

Comment: You will get it inside the nginx pod at /usr/local/nginx/conf, /etc/nginx, or /usr/local/etc/nginx location